# Are there languages which compile to Objective-C or are binary compatible with Objective-C -> Coffeescript for Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, coffeescript

I recently discovered the [eero programming lanugage](http://eerolanguage.org/)
I find the concept of it very interesting. It seems to be mostly syntactic sugar which looks very readable.

Although it does not compile directly to Objective-C it claims to produce the same binary code as Objective-C

> Eero compiles down to the same binary code as Objective-C
>
> Eero offers excellent, nearly seamless interoperability with
>   Objective-C, C, and C++.

I find this approach very interesting and I am wondering if there are similar programming languagues and project which provide a very thigh integration with Objective-C and iOS.
I am looking for something like Coffeescript for Objective-C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the primary way to use eero is to have it compile to native code, it does support source-to-source translation as well (from eero to standard Objective-C/C++). Please see https://github.com/eerolanguage/eero/wiki/Translator for more details.

It really needs to be documented in a more obvious place...